# Visual Studio and SDL2 Window Creation Failing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl

My problem exists with the following code which compiles and runs fine outside of Visual Studio;

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
        printf("%s", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;    

}
```

This problem comes from a much larger program, but is the exact same problem with this simple example. The program runs fine until the declaration of `window`, when the program stops responding to windows, and crashes. All of my previous SDL projects can no longer run inside visual studio, but still run fine outside the IDE.

I have just reinstalled and reset all user settings on Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. I am using up to date library files of SDL 2.0.4, compiled by myself. I'm building the configuration for Debug x86.

**EDIT:** I uped the sensitivity of the debugger in VS, and I got this exception when creating the window,

```
Execption thrown at 0x101EB0B9 (swwxijqt.dll) in SDL_Text.exe: 0xC0000096:
Privileged instruction.
```

Comment: Did you try using Visual Studio's awesome debugger to find out why it crashes?

Comment: I can use the debugger on every line of code before `window` but as soon as I hit continue on declaration, it crashes and doesn't pass any exception.

Comment: However that comment made me think of the sensitivity of the breakpoints in VS, so I enabled all break points, the exception I got is edited into the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no knowledge of what happened, or how to fix it, but I did the one thing that's guaranteed to fix a problem that you don't control. Reinstalling Windows fixed my problem. Something must have been bad with that DLL, and there was no way around it.